# Can Sergi be saved?

Tags: papers-please

On Day 26, Sergi (a border guard that you've become friends with) gets shot in a terrorist attack.  I played through twice and tried to shoot the terrorist before he shot Sergi, but no luck -- I was slightly too slow both times.  Is it possible to save him?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I saved him many times. I don't have a screenshot to prove it, so only a comment. Tip: keep the key to the guns on the right side, near the inspect button, so it is closer to the gun lock.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. When the barrier drops and you hear the alarm, you have a couple of seconds to move the mouse over to the key before the gun cabinet lock is available. Use those seconds to prime yourself for fast action and remember that you only have 3 darts for each terrorist event. If Sergi isn't killed he moves away with his girlfriend (if you let her through the checkpoint).

Comment: *"If Sergi isn't killed he moves away with his girlfriend"* - And they give you money :)

Answer (score 0):

you can blow up both bikes with 1 shot if placed right then the 2nd shot go's to the man that throws the frag